# How to find managers emails and PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName and exported to CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a CSV file with list of users. I am trying to run the script below to collect their managers email name and `PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName` and exported to CSV file. I'm using the below script.

1- My first issue I'm not able to add `PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName` to my script. I have this script that get the `PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName` for a single user

```bash
$user = "user1" |Get-ADUser -Properties physicaldeliveryofficename | Select-Object -ExpandProperty physicaldeliveryofficename | sort-object -Unique
```

But I could add it to my original script to output the `PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName` too.

2- My Second issue is I want to keep blank lines. So if the user list have blank lines I would the output list to keep those same blank lines.

```bash
$user = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\List.csv' | get-aduser -properties manager, PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName


$managerHash = $user.manager | Sort-Object -Unique | Get-ADUser -Properties emailaddress | Group-Object distinguishedname -AsHashTable

     $user | Select-Object SamAccountName,PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
    @{ n = 'ManagerName'; e = { $managerHash[$PSItem.Manager].Name }},
    @{ n = 'ManagerEmailAddress'; e = { $managerHash[$PSItem.Manager].EmailAddress }} | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\List2.csv"
```

Comment: Group-Object creates an array of object under the property Group.  To debug using Format -Table   : $managerHash | Format-Table.  Or  : $managerHash | Foreach { $_.Group | Format-Table}

Comment: You just need to add `PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName` to `-Properties` (first line of code) then the same in the `Select-Object` statement

Comment: Regarding keeping blank lines on the exported Csv I dont understand why you want that and doing something like that only complicates your code

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thank you for you comment. I changed the code. Still not working what did I miss ?

Comment: you want the `PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName` of the Manager or of the User or for Both? Its not quite clear for me

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I want the PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName of the User.

Comment: You're already doing it with `$user | Select-Object SamAccountName,PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I'm not very familiar with PowerShell. What do I need to change to get it to work ?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, you're already properly querying the users `PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName`. Your export CSV should already have a `PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName` column for the users. The calculated property `@{ n = 'Office'; e = { $managerHash[$PSItem.Manager].PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName }}` shouldnt be there tho (this would be the managers Office).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon the issue that it's not working  the output csv file having "False value" in each cell